# Could not initialise JsonSchemaValidator

Tags: mule, jsonschema, anypoint-studio, json-schema-validator

I am using Json schema Validator in mule flow. There are many flows in one project which are using same json schema validator.
Whenever I tried to run the project, which is imported from SVN, it gives an error as **Could not initialise JsonSchemaValidator**. 
I could not find the reason for it. ow should I resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your code snippet and schema please. Most probably either your schema is invalid or mule is unable to read your schema file..

Comment: Yes. reason for error was path for schema location was not valid.

Comment: I try to deploy same application on cloudhub, its giving same error after resolving the error on local. Locally it was working fine but gives error on cloudhub.

Comment: You still haven't show the error details nor the configuration. It is not possible to understand the issue that way.